# COPY NULL values in Postgresql using psycopg2 copy_from()

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

This seems like a rather popular question, but all the answers around here did not help me solve the issue... I have a Postgresql 9.5 table on my OS X machine:

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 TEXT, col2 INT)
```

The following function uses the psycopg2 [`copy_from()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) command:

```
def test_copy(conn, curs, data):
    cpy = BytesIO()
    for row in data:
         cpy.write('\t'.join([str(x) for x in row]) + '\n')
    print cpy
    cpy.seek(0)
    curs.copy_from(cpy, 'test')

test_copy(connection, [('a', None), ('b', None)])
```

And will result in this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "None"
CONTEXT:  COPY test, line 1, column col2: "None"
STATEMENT:  COPY test FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER AS '    ' NULL AS '\N'
```

I tried also `curs.copy_from(cpy, 'test', null='')`, `curs.copy_from(cpy, 'test', null='NULL')`. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, after more trial & error I found the solution:

```
copy_from(cpy, 'test', null='None')
```

Comment: If you are using `csv.write` on an `io.StringIO` then `null=''` works (`psycopg2 2.8`, `postgresql 13`)